# Sorting NSDictionary based UITableView by key

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, sorting, nsdictionary

I have a custom UITableView populated by JSON data brought into a NSMutableDictionary. I then create a mutablecopy so that I can add the value of the distanceFromLocation method to the dictionary. What I am trying to do is to then sort the the cells by the closest distance using that new object. I have looked at other examples of using NSSortDescriptor, but that is talking about sorting arrays. How can I either sort the cells from the dictionary or create an array from the dictionary to use the NSSortDescriptor?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dealerlistcell";

DealerListCell *cell = (DealerListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[DealerListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//gets JSON data and loads into Dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableDictionary *infocopy = [info mutableCopy];

//pulls the current user location
CLLocation *currentlocation2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

//gets the latitude and longitude from info dictionary to calculate distancefromlocation for each cell
CLLocation *locationforindex = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[info objectForKey:@"dlrlat"]doubleValue] longitude:[[info objectForKey:@"dlrlong"]doubleValue]];

//calculates the distance
CLLocationDistance dist = ([locationforindex distanceFromLocation:currentlocation2]*0.0006213711922);

//format the distance to a string for the label
NSString *distancestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f miles",dist];

//create object with distance to add to dictionary
NSNumber *distance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:dist];
```

**EDIT:** Assigned distance to object to call later in NSSortDescriptor

```
//add to dictionary 
[infocopy setObject:distance forKey:@"distance"];

//create array from dictionary
NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:infocopy];
NSArray *anArray = [aDict allValues];

//implemented NSSortDescriptor
NSSortDescriptor *sorter [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending: YES];
NSArray *sortdescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter];
[anArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptors];
```

However it throws valueForUndefinedKey for the key distance. How do I define the distance key in "initWithKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some help from this forum and my friends, I was able to piece this solution together.

The answer was to use a for loop and create dictionaries for each location in a method before it loads the table view. Then I used a NSSortDescriptor to do the sorting, and it worked perfectly.

See the code below for the final solution.

```
-(void)getData:(NSData *) data 
{

NSError *error;

// load the jsonArray with the JSON Data
jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];


//define the unsorted dealers array
unsortedDealers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];

// start at row 0
int index = 0;

// loop through each dealer and calculate distance from current location
for (NSDictionary *dealer in jsonArray) 
{
    //create dictionary from JSON Array
    infoDict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:index];

    //get the coordidates from current location
    CLLocation *currentlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

    //get the coordinates for dealer at row
    // dlr lat and longs are switched in the database
    CLLocation *locationforindex = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrlong"]doubleValue] longitude:[[infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrlat"]doubleValue]];

    //calculate the distance from current location to dealer at row and format it in miles
    CLLocationDistance dist = ([locationforindex distanceFromLocation:currentlocation]*0.0006213711922);

    //define the distance for display
    NSNumber *distanceForDict = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:dist];

    //define the distance for sorting
    NSString *distanceForSort = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",dist];

   //create a dictionary for each dealer and define the values for each key 
   NSMutableDictionary *dealerDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrname"] , @"dlrname", [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrcity"], @"dlrcity", [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrstate"] , @"dlrstate", [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrzip"], @"dlrzip", [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlradd"] , @"dlradd", distanceForDict , @"dlrdistance" , distanceForSort , @"dlrsortdistance" , [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlremail"] , @"dlremail" , [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrfax"] , @"dlrfax" , [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrhours"] , @"dlrhours" , [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrlat"], @"dlrlat",[infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrlong"] , @"dlrlong" , [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrnum"], @"dlrnum",[infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrphone"] , @"dlrphone" , [infoDict objectForKey:@"dlrwebsite"], @"dlrwebsite", nil];

    //add dictionary to the unsorted array
    [unsortedDealers addObject:dealerDict];

    // iterate through the list of dealers
    ++index;

}

// creates the sorting element
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;

//define what you want to sort by
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dlrdistance" ascending:YES];

// build new array with thosed elements to be sorted
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

// create new array based on the sorted value
sortedDealers = [unsortedDealers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];  

[self.tableView reloadData];

//error message if there is no data found. Usually this is an error with the connection, 
//it should never return empty
if (jsonArray ==  nil) 
{
    NSLog(@"No Data Loaded. Please check your internet connection");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:info];
NSArray *anArray = [aDict allValues];
```

It will return an array that you can then sort using an NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: It throws a valueForUndefinedKey when I try to use  "distance" in the NSSortDescriptor

Comment: Sorry, but what sort of objects does your array contain? If I'm not mistaken, it should be an array of dictionaries so that the sort descriptor has keys on each object in the array to compare. I'm sort of new to this but I think that's what's going on.

Comment: It starts with a JSON Serialization into an NSDictionary called _info_. It has values such as name of the location, address, etc, and keys such as _dlrname_, _dlrcity_, etc. I have since figured out how to insert the _distanceFromLocation_ into a value with a corresponding key. Using NSLog, I have verified the distance (NSNumber) is stored in the key _distance_. The problem I am having is how to use the NSSortDescriptor to sort the UITableView based off of the distance

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. But is there only the one NSDictionary in your array? Or are there several, each representing a location? If the latter is the case, and you have confirmed that the values by which you would like to sort are associated with the distance key, then it should only be a matter of 

NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];
"array" is the one that contains your dictionaries. log that and results should be sorted.

Comment: then you would use sortedArray as the data for populating your table.

Comment: As much as I appreciate you helping me, and am very grateful for your time, I seem to be making things more difficult. It is only one dictionary in the array.

Comment: I'm happy to help. So, help me understand on a basic level, what exactly would you like your table to display? It looks like maybe nearby car dealerships? And you want the closest one to show up at the top of the list? But in order to do that, we need a dictionary for each dealer like this [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@"A Dealership", 8.5 forKeys:@"locationName", @"distance"];
Once you have a dict for each dealer in your array, then you can sort by any key present in the dict. Am I misunderstanding you? Is that helpful?

Comment: That is exactly it, would I define those new dictionaries using a for loop in my cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: No, if you make the dictionaries there, you would be mutating your data set whilst enumerating it, which is a no-no. I would do it in viewDidLoad, probably. That's where I would add those objects to the array as well.